# How should I handle the structure of my app (ListView inception)?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I will try to describe my question as clearly as possible here. I am a novice developer and I am having trouble deciding how to correctly organize my app. Hopefully some of you guys can provide me with some insight on the best practices.

I have a FragmentActivity called Form.java. This activity is supported by tabbed navigation. One of these tabs displays a Fragment called SymptomBrowser. This fragment is basically a list view, with the option of the user adding his own items (there is a Add Symptom button).

The AddSymptom Button opens a List of all the available items that can be added to SymptomBrowser. When one of those items is selected, the user is brought to a form inquiring about that particular item.

In short: Form.java -> SymptomBrowser Fragment -> Fragment with the list of all symptoms -> Edit that particular symptom and store form data.

There are over 50 symptoms. Should I add 50 different fragments for each? Or should I have one fragment and many different layouts? Am I doing this correctly? How should I organize the app structure?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one single fragment filled with TextViews and stuff. All the symptoms must share common data, e.g. name, description, etc.

When you "load" a symptom, you basically change the data inside the same fragment.

Comment: The thing is the layout is different for each symptom. Like completely different. Of course they share some little details in the composition of the layout, but they are mostly different.

Comment: The you need a layout for each group of similar symptoms. If all 50 symptoms are irremediably different, then I'm sorry but you will need 50 layouts.

Comment: But yes I get what your saying, that's what I was initially thinking of.